# Using C code from C++ using autotools

Tags: c++, c, linker

I am writing a (my first) C++ class on top of some code written in C, but I can only get the C++ to compile by declaring the C functions in a extern block. My project uses autotools; is there any way to automate this process so I don't have to maintain two header files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes create wrapper header files which include your C header files like so...

```
//Wrapper.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{

    #include "Actual.h"
}
#else
    #include "Actual.h"
#endif


//Use.cpp
#include "Wrapper.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

//Use.c
#include "Wrapper.h"
/*or #include "Actual.h" */

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this certainly works, I think the much higher-rated answer below is better - use the preprocessor in the actual header files to declare the functions `extern "C"`. That way, you can include the header the same way in C and C++, and not have to worry about an extra "wrapper" header.

Comment: True but what if the actual header cannot be modified? What if it was obtained from a third party/another project whose sources are not being maintained by you?

Answer (score 15):

Use a extern block inside a #ifdef in C codes header files

Start of header files

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

...and at end of the header files

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This way it will work for being included in both C and C++ sources

Answer (score 1):

Use the C Preprocessor.  Do something like this:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif 
// code goes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a macro in a header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define _crtn "C"
#else
    #define _crtn
#endif
```

Then in header files, we can use `_crtn`:

```
#include "croutine.h"

extern _crtn void MyFunction( ... );
```

The only gotcha is to make sure you include the header file containing the prototype of MyFunction inside the file containing the implementation of MyFunction so that it is compiled with "C" linkage.

This is the same as @epatel's answer, but only requires the ugly `#ifdef`'s in one header file.

Comment: Little-known fact: you can declare functions as extern "C++", although it's kind of pointless since it's the default when compiling with C++, and C compilers can't compile C++.  But it may be useful in the future for the hypothetical C++++ language.